# How do I selectively stack columns with twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a template based on fluid example here:
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html

I have the latest files from here, the only customizations being colors:
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html

The basic markup is

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">
      <div class="well sidebar-nav">
    Column 1
      </div><!--/.well -->
    </div><!--/span-->
    <div class="span9">
    Column 2
    </div><!--/span-->
  </div><!--/row-->
</div>
```

Column 2 falls under column 1 on mobile devices, which is what I want sometimes.  But in some cases (specific pages) I want the 2 columns to remain side by side.  My question is how do I achieve this with the same js/css files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possibility: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/RMPMA/

You will see that the columns don't drop on the row with class = double-col
CSS

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
.double-col.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
float: left;
width: 50%;

}
}
```

Since this resets the width of each col to 50% on viewpoints 767px and below, this will work with rows having two columns. For other combinations, simply play with the width setting. You might also want refine the padding and other styling, but easy enough now.

Hope this helps!